# How to make a PHP Test suite

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing

Ive been looking around and i didn't find any good information about test suites, could anyone please explain how it should look like.

I found this example:

```
require_once 'MyTest.php';

class MySuite extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite
{
    public static function suite()
    {
        return new MySuite('MyTest');
    }

    protected function setUp()
    {
        print "\nMySuite::setUp()";
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        print "\nMySuite::tearDown()";
    }
}
```

There are few things i understand and some not, i know that i shall include my testcase, like include 'Test.php';

I want to make a testsuite that contains all my testcases, how should this testsuite look like? I tried a example i found at the itnernet and i got this error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_Exception' with message 'Argument #1 of PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite::addTestSuite() must be a class name or object' in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\InvalidArgumentHelper.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php(288): PHPUnit_Util_InvalidArgumentHelper::factory(1, 'class name or o...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\exem\MyTestSuite.php(13): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestSuite('testFunctions')
#2 [internal function]: AllTests::suite('AllTests')
#3 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php(124): ReflectionMethod->invoke(NULL, 'AllTests')
#4 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(150): PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest('mytestsuite', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#6 C:\xampp\php\phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#7 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\InvalidArgumentHelper.php on line 69
```

Could you write me or show me an example of how a testsuite looks like? how the code look like.

My Testfile looks like this:

```
include 'functions.php';

class Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase 
{

    protected function getConnection()
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli('local', 'root', '', 'db_13839918');

        if($mysqli->connect_errno > 0){
            die('Unable to connect to database [' . $mysqli->connect_error . ']');
        }
    }

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_13839918');

        $now = time();
        $i = 0;

        do {
            $i = $i+1;
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts (user_id, time) VALUES ('4892388', '$now')");

        } while ($i < 6);
    }

    public function testCheckbrute()
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_13839918');

        $LessThanFive = checkbrute('4892389', $mysqli);
        $this->assertFalse($LessThanFive);

        $FiveFailedLogins = checkbrute('4892388', $mysqli);
        $this->assertTrue($FiveFailedLogins);
    }

    public function testLogin()
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_13839918');

        $AccountIsLockedFalse = Login("xxxxx","xxx", $mysqli);
        $this->assertFalse($AccountIsLockedFalse);

        $NoUserExists = Login("xxxxxx","xxxxx", $mysqli);
        $this->assertFalse($NoUserExists);
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_13839918');
        $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM members WHERE id IN (9, 11)");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question to be more specific. What part do you not understand? What errors did you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

What does 'MyTest.php' look like?

This error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_Exception' with message 'Argument #1 of PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite::addTestSuite() must be a class name or object'
```

means that this line, `return new MySuite('MyTest');` is causing problems.

Change it to `return new MySuite('Test');`  The string passed to MySuite needs to be the name of the class that contains the tests.

PHPUnit is looking for a class called MyTest and not finding it.

Comment: Yes i already did that. I got this message:

MySuite::setUp()
MySuite::tearDown()
Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 1.50Mb
No tests executed!

I guess something is missing